# Density function in R - straight lines?

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
x <- c(3000,6000,9000)
w <- c(0.4,0.5,0.1)

y<- density(x,weights=w,from=1000, to = 10000)
plot(y)
```

Now it seems as though the density function is smoothing between the points specified. I would like it to be such that there is a straight line from 1000-3000, then another straight line from 3000 to 6000, 6000-9000 and finally 9000-10000. Is there a way to do this with the density function?

Comment: A kernel density estimate with a gaussian kernel will in general not have straight lines. If you want to plot straight lines, why not just do `plot(x, w, type = "l")`? By the way, I'd suggest reading up on KDE if you use it and haven't already. It's quite a simple and elegant method.

Comment: @alanocallaghan I'm not trying to just plot straight lines but will need the density to be straight lines too as I am going to sample from it. I will read on KDE - thanks

Comment: In that case, you need to use a kernel which has uniformly decreasing density away from its mean, rather than a gaussian kernel which is, well, gaussian :)

Comment: I realise there's a better way of saying "uniformly decreasing density". The slope of the kernel function should be constant, say `m`. It should switch sign at the mean, say `+m` below the mean and `-m` above the mean. I don't know of such a kernel but it doesn't sound too complex.

Comment: Are you seriously estimating an empirical distribution from three values?

Comment: @Roland This is just an example... I was advised to put a reproducible example and that is what I have done...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : The image you shared give explicit density function formula defined per segment. I would advise you too write down the calculus to have a real density function with you points (x and p). Then you can plot it as shown bellow.

You could plot explicit points and lines such as the following. It is no density though (Area under curve greater than 1).

```r
x <- c(1000, 3000, 6000, 9000, 10000)
w <- c(0, 0.4,0.5,0.1, 0)
plot(x, w, type = "b")
```

[image]

**Or using ggplot2 :**

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
dfr <- tibble(x, w)
dfr %>% 
        ggplot(aes(x, w)) +
        geom_point() +
        geom_line()
```

[image]

But as commented before with your number of values an histogram would be a better representation.

Comment: Thanks - but I am trying to estimate a density which the the straight lines. Basically, I would like to get the density that the plot you have shown has.

Comment: Well from the amount of data you have you should consider a discrete density. What do you mean by density ? Can you write down the partition function ?

Comment: I would like it to be continuous between the points selected, or if it is discrete then the points will need to be very small. Not sure what you mean by partition function, but the effective CDF and PDF are here: https://imgur.com/a/aZhc0OH

Comment: Alright you have both CDF and PDF that are defined. You don't need the density function (you would do so if you are trying to estimate it from a sample). You should write you density function as a sum of local density f_i(x_i, p_i) defined on [x_i, x_(i+1) [